# I reviewed some posts but it only shows I reviewed one

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review

In the [first posts](https://islam.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts) review task, I reviewed about 5 posts, but it only shows I reviewed 1 post.

Comment: What actions did you select? Selecting "Not Sure" doesn't count as a review.

Comment: @ChrisF only about 2 of them I selected (not sure).  I did select more than one as done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a timing issue I have encountered before.

If you and some other user are reviewing the same post at almost the same time. Only the first is recorded.

Comment: hmm, I never knew that cool.  There is no umm (evidences) that there was user beside me reviewing, perhaps in other queues, but not this one.

Comment: @AlUmmat Someone got to it before you.

Comment: @Austin Henley yes, a day before but perhaps this is the answer.